# getting roc_auc_score nan for cross validation of multiclass classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, roc, auc

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem with imbalanced data with 3 classes, I used stratifiedkfolds to split data and SMOTE method to oversample it.
when I use cross-validation to evaluate my models I get results for F1_score but for roc_auc I only get nan value

```
for key, classifier in classifiers.items():
    classifier.fit(X_sm, y_sm)
    training_score1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_sm, y_sm,scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='macro', labels=[2]), cv=5)
    print("Classifiers: ", classifier.__class__.__name__, "Has a training score of", round(training_score1.mean(), 2) * 100, "% F1  score")
    training_score2 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_sm, y_sm,scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, average='macro',multi_class='ovo'), cv=5)
    print("Classifiers: ", classifier.__class__.__name__, "Has a training score of", round(training_score2.mean(), 2) * 100, "% Roc_auc score")
```

X_sm and y_sm are both arrays and the results in this case are:

```
Classifiers:  LogisticRegression Has a training score of 77.0 % F1  score
Classifiers:  LogisticRegression Has a training score of nan % Roc_auc score
Classifiers:  KNeighborsClassifier Has a training score of 94.0 % F1  score
Classifiers:  KNeighborsClassifier Has a training score of nan % Roc_auc score
Classifiers:  SVC Has a training score of 89.0 % F1  score
Classifiers:  SVC Has a training score of nan % Roc_auc score
Classifiers:  DecisionTreeClassifier Has a training score of 83.0 % F1  score
Classifiers:  DecisionTreeClassifier Has a training score of nan % Roc_auc score
```

I tried to use `cross_validate` but it's not working for me.

Comment: Try setting `error_score="raise"` in the `cross_val_score`; if then you get an error, report the full traceback of that error in the question. // You should at least be using `needs_proba=True` in the `make_scorer`.  (Why do you only look at the F1 score of class 2, but want the ovo AUCs?)

Comment: Class 2 is my minority class, I used label[2] to check it and just forgot to remove it before posting my problem. When I set `error_score="raise"` it returns this error `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`. But when I used `needs_proba=True` it's working for all the classifiers except SVC that returns this error for auc_roc_score: `predict_proba is not available when  probability=False` and not working at all for f1 score it returns in this case the error : `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets`

Comment: The full traceback (not just the final error message), and edited into the Question (not just added as a comment).

Answer (score 1):

The auROC metric requires a continuous confidence measure, as opposed to the hard class predictions, so you need to set `needs_proba=True` or `needs_threshold=True`. The latter uses the classifier's `decision_function` or `predict_proba`, whereas the first only tries to use `predict_proba`; since SVMs are not natively probabilistic, you'll want `needs_threshold`.  (Do not set either of these for F1, which only uses hard class predictions.)

Comment: It's working now I set `probability=True` on the SVC classifier and `needs_proba=True` on the `roc_auc_score` metric, and it's ok now. I have tried `needs_treshold` but it doesn't work they return an error of `multiclass format not supported` but it's fine now with `needs_proba` thank you.